# Shadowing Remote Desktop Sessions: Restricting access to certain users

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop

I am allowing some users in my organization to shadow Remote Desktop Sessions of users on our Remote Desktop Services deployment. I am facing the problem that the users that I have allowed the "Remote Control" right (via Remote Desktop Session Host Configuration) can shadow ALL sessions ....

Is there a way to restrict the access to sessions of certain users/groups?

I am using Remote Desktop Services on Windows Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there's no way to control which users can be shadowed.